# Highslide: dimmingOpacity and doctype in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: highslide

I'm using Highslide (which I'm delighted with) very successfully in Chrome, Firefox and IE9, but it is not behaving correctly in IE 10. I'm using the dimmingOpacity property to dim my thumbnail background when an image expands, but in IE 10, the background remains unchanged. After much trial and error, the problem seems to be something to do with doctype. A Highslide barebones example (http://highslide.com/examples/mini-gallery.html) actually dims correctly in IE 10, and the only significant difference I can see with my code is the doctype used. What's more, if I take a copy of that source and change the doctype to mine (!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"), then the sample's dimming doesn't work (in IE 10). Conversely, if I use the sample's doctype (!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "xhtml11.dtd") in my code, then it dims correctly, but all sorts of other things on the page get screwed up.

I'll be extremely grateful for any help - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The dimming will work properly in IE10 if you use the full, valid DOCTYPE declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

You're missing part of it.

But now for the lecture. HTML "transitional" was designed to ease the transition from HTML 3.2 to HTML 4.0, back in the late 1990's. It's a moldy old relic. XHMTL isn't much better, and is now a dead letter. This is an old thread, but still worth some perusal, particularly on the subject of why XHTML was always a fake, anyway: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?393445-xhtml-vs-html-faq

Do yourself a big favor and start coding your pages for HTML5. It's not really very difficult, and it will help you future-proof your pages. Sticking with obsolete DOCTYPE's is becoming a minefield, as you have just discovered!